# Guardar o conteudo de um ficheiro noutro ficheiro - python

Tags: python, string, arquivo

Estou a tentar ler informação de um ficheiro e guardá-la num novo ficheiro, após passar toda a informação para minúsculas e retirar caracteres de pontuação. Para isto criei uma função ReadFile() que lê o ficheiro em causa e o guarda numa variável global, data. Após ler o ficheiro e armazenar a informação na variável data vai passar para minúsculas e retirar os caracteres especiais através da função PunctuactionLowercase(). E por fim, eu queria guardar esta nova informação num novo ficheiro, no entanto não estou a conseguir. Alguém me pode ajudar?

```
import string
data=[]
dataLower=[]
dataPunctuation=[]

def ReadFile():
    global data
    f=open("chap.1_esp.txt",'r')
    while True:
        line=f.readline()        
        if not line:
            break
        data.append(line)

    f.close()
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print(data[i],end=" ")

def PunctuationLowercase():
    global data, dataLower, dataPunctuation
    translator=str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        dataLower.append(data[i].lower())   
        dataPunctuation.append(dataLower[i].translate(translator)) 
        print(dataPunctuation[i],end=" ") 

def SaveFile():
    global data, dataLower, dataPunctuation

    texto="Isto é uma variável que vai ser guardada num ficheiro."
    with open("chap.1_new.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(texto)   
        f.write("Isto vai ser guardado num ficheiro.")
        for i in range(len(data)):
                f.write(dataPunctuation.append(dataLower[i])

    f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ReadFile()
    PunctuationLowercase()
    SaveFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Acredito que você precise utilizar as variáveis globais de uma outra forma e um outro ponto seria com relação à escrita no arquivo (cada um com sua responsabilidade). segue código rodando:

```
import string

def ReadFile():
    global data
    f=open("chap.1_esp.txt",'r')
    data = f.read()
    while True:
        line=f.readline()        
        if not line:
            break
        data.append(line)

    f.close()
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print(data[i],end=" ")

def PunctuationLowercase():
    global dataLower
    global dataPunctuation
    dataLower = []
    dataPunctuation = []
    translator=str.maketrans('','', string.punctuation)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        dataLower.append(data[i].lower())   
        dataPunctuation.append(dataLower[i].translate(translator)) 
        print(dataPunctuation[i],end=" ") 

def SaveFile():
    texto="Isto é uma variável que vai ser guardada num ficheiro."
    with open("chap.1_new.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(texto)   
        f.write("Isto vai ser guardado num ficheiro.")
        for i in range(len(data)):
                dataPunctuation.append(dataLower[i]) #primeiro atribuir o valor
                f.write(dataPunctuation[i]) #depois escrever

    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ReadFile()
    PunctuationLowercase()
    SaveFile()
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante!!

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil, peço que vote nela para pontuar e assim possa ajudar outras pessoas na comunidade. Abraços,